# How to download google sheets file to specific folder in cpanel using wget cron

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, wget

I have a working cron job but I can't get it to download my file into my target destination. At the moment, the file is downloaded into the root folder in cpanel.

Here is what I have:

```
wget --no-check-certificate 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[...]/edit?usp=sharing' -O file.xlsx
```

Now defining the destination folder doesn't work. Here's how I'm doing it:

```
wget --no-check-certificate 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[...]/edit?usp=sharing' -O 'public_html/wp-content/uploads/import/files' file.xlsx
```

This doesn't download any file. Not sure what I could be missing.

Answer (score 0):

Managed with this:

```
wget --no-check-certificate 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[...]/edit?usp=sharing' -O public_html/wp-content/uploads/import/files/file.xlsx
```